# How do I make the same git commit as I did on another branch using that commit id?

Tags: git

I made a big git mess. The commits are somewhere in git but I dont know where, I can see them using git show (first four characters of commit id). I'm building a the branch up from scratch and want to make these same commits as I did before, so that I do not have to rewrite all the code from git show.

Comment: Please describe better your situation, for example provide a graph of your current branches, will you throw away the other branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) command does exactly that.

From the documentation:

> Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits